# Google sheets text date conversion

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column with various dates in text format like this - 1st January 2017 or 24th December 2017.

Is it possible to extract the DATE from that so I can have it in the format DD/MM/YYYY?

Answer (score 1):

This will work. Assumes dates are in column A starting in row 2. Enter this in B2:

```
=iferror(arrayformula(datevalue(regexreplace($A2:$A100,"((st)|(th)|(nd))",""))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant (but should work!):

```
=if(ISNUMBER(mid(A2,2,1)*1),date(right(A2,4),match(mid(A2,find(" ",A2)+1,3),MonthNo.,0),left(A2,2)),date(right(A2,4),match(mid(A2,find(" ",A2)+1,3),MonthNo.,0),left(A2,2)))
```

Assumes a range named `MonthNo.` is populated with `Jan`, `Feb`, `Mar` etc.